# How do I calculate percentage of a subset of rows in R data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a simpler way of doing the following using `data.table` without the need for `nrow`?

`df[A, .N/nrow(df)]`

(Where `A` is some condition.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no much more simpler way. You are welcome to propose one but it is hard to imagine more simple than the one you wrote. One option is:

```r
df[, sum(A)/.N]
```

For future question please include reproducible example that can be copy pasted into R.